# How to merge C# list records with the records in same list

Tags: c#, linq, list, merge

I have the following linq

```
var unionOperations =
      (from r in gropOperations
       select new
          {
            r.OPERATIONID,
            r.OPERATIONNAME,
            r.ISACTIVE
          })
       .Union(from m in customOperations
              select new
                {
                    m.OPERATIONID,
                    m.OPERATIONNAME,
                    m.ISACTIVE
                }
              );
```

it is returning list of objects as follows,

```
{ OPERATIONID = 1050, OPERATIONNAME = "NEW", ISACTIVE = TRUE }
{ OPERATIONID = 1050, OPERATIONNAME = "NEW", ISACTIVE = FALSE }
{ OPERATIONID = 1051, OPERATIONNAME = "EDIT", ISACTIVE = TRUE  }
{ OPERATIONID = 1052, OPERATIONNAME = "DELETE", ISACTIVE = TRUE  }
{ OPERATIONID = 1053, OPERATIONNAME = "PRINT", ISACTIVE = TRUE  }
```

Now I want a list as follows:

```
{ OPERATIONID = 1050, OPERATIONNAME = "NEW", TRUE  } 
{ OPERATIONID = 1051, OPERATIONNAME = "EDIT", TRUE }
{ OPERATIONID = 1052, OPERATIONNAME = "DELETE", TRUE }
{ OPERATIONID = 1053, OPERATIONNAME = "PRINT", TRUE }
```

What really has happened is it merged the first two records(OPERATIONID = 1050) with their "or" operation of the `ISACTIVE` values;

Comment: Why are you shouting at us?

Comment: Close your caps lock btw..

Comment: sry if you feel that i'm shouting. this is my first post and im not good with english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = unionOperations.GroupBy(x => x.OPERATIONID)
                .Select(g => {
                    var item = g.First();
                    return new {
                        OPERATIONID = item.OPERATIONID,
                        OPERATIONNAME =item.OPERATIONNAME,
                        ISACTIVE = g.Aggregate(false, (r, x) => r |= x.ISACTIVE)
                    };
                })
                .ToList();
```